# Tag for removal - heater

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[heater](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/heater) - Stupid tag used by a single closed question. I think we can safely get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the tag from the question. Hopefully, the tag will be forgotten in time...

Comment: Why not get rid of it altogether?

Comment: @Karan: I can't. If a tag is not used, it will be removed from the system automatically after a while. Tags that are more commonly used can be removed by developers only.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. (BTW, what's "a while"?)

Comment: @Karan: According to latest reports, [24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154855/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-tag-specifically-jodatimetime). Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-burninate-a-tag-themselves

Comment: I'm with lunboks; I too am surprised mods can't do this already. Oh well, guess 24h is not that long a time to wait - who's in a hurry to burninate anyway? :)